# How to convert Json string with key-value pair into string with only values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to convert JSON string with key-value pair into string with only values in javascript.

For example my JSON output looks like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "BearCollection": {
      "BearDetails": [
        {
          "Name": "James",
          "x": "81.43410000",
          "y": "6.32813300"
        },
        {
          "Name": "James",
          "x": "81.43489000",
          "y": "6.32763300"
        },
        {
          "Name": "Sera",
          "x": "81.4377000",
          "y": "6.32453300"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "xhr": {}
}
```

I want to convert it using javascript as

```
var details=[
  [
    "James",
    81.4341,
    6.328133
  ],
  [
    "James",
    81.43489,
    6.327633
  ],
  [
    "Sera",
    81.4377,
    6.324533
  ]
];
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse();` and iterate through the json objects and build the required data.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = "Your JSON string";
obj = JSON.parse(json);

for(int i= 0; i< obj.data.BearCollection.BearDetails.length;i++)
{
   String Name = obj.data.BearCollection.BearDetails[i].Name;
   String x = obj.data.BearCollection.BearDetails[i].x;
   String y = obj.data.BearCollection.BearDetails[i].y;

  ..fill Array (pseudo - do some work yourself ;) )
}
```

Comment: the question asked for JavaScript?

Comment: @Bergi and the code above is?
(Except for som pseudo)

Comment: StackOverflow is in my eyes help to help yourself.  Not to get complete solutions. But that's my opinion.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, but you might should have stated that. Especially the type annotations confused me, and `…fill Array` should be marked as a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = JSON.parse('{"data": {"BearCollection": {"BearDetails": [{"Name": "James","x": "81.43410000","y": "6.32813300"},{"Name": "James","x": "81.43489000","y": "6.32763300"},{"Name": "Sera","x": "81.4377000","y": "6.32453300"}]}},"xhr": {}}');

var bear;
var arr = [];
var nestedArr;
for (i in data.data.BearCollection.BearDetails) {
    bear = data.data.BearCollection.BearDetails[i];

    nestedArr = [];
    nestedArr.push(bear.Name);
    nestedArr.push(bear.x);
    nestedArr.push(bear.y);

    arr.push(nestedArr);
}

});
```

Comment: Have a look at [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` to get the object from the JSON string, then access the BearDetails, convert each element to an array, and stringify the new collection again:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
var details = obj.data.BearCollection.BearDetails.map(function(detail) {
    return [detail.Name, detail.x, detail.y];
});
return JSON.stringify(details);
```